# maven assembly include all sub-module dependencies without "already added, skipping"

Tags: maven-2, maven-3, maven-assembly-plugin

So I have a parent module with a bunch of sub-modules, and I'm trying to generate a zip file with all of the module jars and all of their dependencies. My assembly descriptor looks like (similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436359/maven-assembly-plugin-include-dependencies-from-sub-modules)):

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>bin</id>
    <formats>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>
            <binaries>
                <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
                <dependencySets>
                    <dependencySet>
                        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
                        <unpack>false</unpack>
                        <scope>runtime</scope>
                    </dependencySet>
                </dependencySets>
            </binaries>
        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

Now in both maven 2 and maven 3 I'm seeing hundreds of messages that look like:

```
[INFO] distribution-0.5.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/commons-lang-2.4.jar already added, skipping
[INFO] distribution-0.5.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/spring-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar already added, skipping
[INFO] distribution-0.5.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/commons-logging-1.0.4.jar already added, skipping
[INFO] distribution-0.5.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/args4j-2.0.12.jar already added, skipping
[INFO] distribution-0.5.1-SNAPSHOT/lib/collections-generic-4.01.jar already added, skipping
```

I gather these are happening because many of my sub-modules share dependencies (and some sub-modules depend on other sub-modules) and maven is copying all transitive dependencies for each sub-module independently so there's a ton of repetition in there.

Is there a way I can keep maven from trying to copy the same dependencies multiple times? Or at least hide these "already added, skipping" messages when it tries to?

Comment: "already added, skipping" does no harm. Latest is already added to your artifact no point in adding (effectively replacing) the same again.

Comment: I agree it does no harm, but it's a sign that something funny is going on - maven is searching for all of these jars multiple times. I find the assembly above takes about 2 minutes to run, while running package on any of the sub-modules takes seconds. It's also disruptive to have 5 or 10 pages of such messages pushing anything else maven might have said before that well off the screen.

Comment: I also came across this problem and decided to create a ticket - http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MASSEMBLY-594. Please vote it up if this is still and issue for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt if there exist anything that allows [Maven Assembly plug-in](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) to mute. This would be a good option to provide.

On other hand, you can ask Maven to suppress all output and run in *quiet* mode.

```
mvn -h
usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]
Options:
  -q,--quiet    Quiet output - only show errors
```

E.g.

```
mvn -q clean package
```

But, you will loose all the other build time information as well.